# Spring mvc test + mockito. @ModelAttribute NullPointer

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, springmockito

I am trying to Unit test a simple Spring-MVC-Controller but even the simplest Unit Test fails because a `@ModelAttribute` throws a `NullpointerException`. My Question is: How to mock/set the `ModelAttribute`?
I've tried mocking the `findAll()` method from the repository but it fails.

Below are my used classes:

**TestContext:**

```
@Configuration
public class TestContext {

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public BenutzerRepository benutzerRepository() {
    return Mockito.mock(BenutzerRepository.class);
}
}
```

**StandaloneBenutzerController:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestContext.class)
public class StandaloneBenutzerControllerTest {

public MockMvc mockMvc;
@Mock
private BenutzerRepository benutzerRepositoryMock;
@Mock
private Benutzer benutzer;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    this.benutzerRepositoryMock = Mockito.mock(BenutzerRepository.class);
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    Benutzer hauke = new Benutzer("test","tester", "test@tester.de");
    List<Benutzer> mockList = new ArrayList<Benutzer>();

    mockList.add(hauke);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new BenutzerController()).setViewResolvers(viewResolver)
            .build();
}

@Test
public void testSimpleStatus() throws Exception {

    Mockito.when(benutzer.getEmail()).thenReturn("test@tester.de");
    //Mockito.when(benutzerRepositoryMock.findAll()).thenCallRealMethod();
    //Mockito.when(benutzerRepositoryMock.findAll()).thenReturn(userList);

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/verwaltung"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/verwaltung.jsp"));
}
}
```

**BenutzerController:** the Part which throws the Nullpointer

```
@ModelAttribute("userList")
public List<Benutzer> userList() {
    return toList(repository.findAll());
}
```

Comment: you have to set the mocked repository in your BenutzerController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is like Si mo hinted to set the mock repository for the tested BenutzerController via the constructor:

```
 mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup( new BenutzerController(benutzerRepositoryMock)).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
```

Comment: I would recomend you to use a setter or even better a constructor to set the repository.
Spring lets you introduce @Autowired contructors. They are a good choice to inject your dependencies and mocks.

`public class MyController (){
 MyDependencyOne one;
 
 MyDependencyTwo two ;
 
 @Autowired
 public MyController (MyDependencyOne one, MyDependencyTwo two){
  this.one = one;
  this.two = two;
 }
}`